# Angular URL sub-path issue with Tomcat

Tags: javascript, angular, tomcat, routes

I have to redirect to a dedicated page from sub-path parameter. It is a specific requirement from my client.

**Example:-**

```
http://localhost:4200/math/ 

http://localhost:4200/science/
```

In the above URLs *math* & *science* are the parameter and i have to redirect to the corresponding pages.

My problem is, It is working fine in localhost( ng serve) but it is not working when i deploy in a tomcat server, It throws 404 error

Example URL : `www.xyz.com/math/ & www.xyz.com/science/`

But i can make the URL valid when i am introducing **#** based routing

`www.xyz.com/#/math/`

Is there any ways to achieve like this `www.xyz.com/math/` in tomcat?

Comment: You have to rewrite the urls to use Location Path Strategy

Comment: The application deep links will not work without the redirect rule on the server. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57792557/1298824) for configuring the fallback on Apache tomcat.