# The url of angular application deployed on local tomcat server doesn't load components on pasting the url on a new tab of the browser

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have deployed an *Angular* app in the local *Tomcat* server and is connected to a *Spring* application which uses a identity server for single sign on.

When I run the application the server on *eclipse* and start the client app, the application works seamlessly, but when I copy the url and paste it on a new tab of the browser the app fails to load a component.

Earlier the url on pasting on a new tab of the browser use to return a 404 error, so I searched and found I had to use location strategy, and uploaded a new dist file, since then the url doesn't return a 404 but instead fails to load a(one) component.

This is from the `app.routing.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{path:'nav', component:NavBarComponent,
children:[
{path:'config', component:ConfigureComponent,
children:[
{path:'tenant', component:TenantComponent},
{path:'department', component:DepartmentComponent},
{path:'adminUser', component:DepartmentUserComponent},
{path:'setting', component:AdminSettingComponent},
{path: 'version', component: VersionManagementComponent},  
{path:'eventType',component:EventTypeComponent},
{path:'workforceUser',component:WorkforceUserComponent},
{path:'dashboard',component:DashboardComponent},
{path:'eform',component:EFormComponent},
{path:'groups',component:GroupsComponent},
{path:'userProfile',component:UserProfileComponent}
 ]},
]},
{ path: '**', component: LoginComponent },
];
```

The `ConfigureComponent` is the one which doesn't load.

Implementing location strategy at `app.module.ts`:

```
import { Location, HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from 
'@angular/common';

providers: [
 {provide:LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
HttpClientService,
AppConfigService,
toastrService,
WorkforceUserService,
AuthGuard
]
```

What changes should I make in the routing so `ConfigureComponent` is not missed out when I copy and paste the url on a new tab, the same thing happens when I refresh the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rewrite the server's routing so that all routes will be redirected to index.html

Answer (score 1):

The application deep links will not work without the redirect rule on the server. All the deep links have to redirect to the application `index.html` by the server.

The browser will then download and load the additional resources needed like angular for the application. Then the angular routing will takeover and show the required components in the view.

Setting this redirect rule (or fallback to `index.html`) for various servers like Apache, Nginx, IIS, GitHub pages and Firebase hosting is mentioned [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml) in the angular docs. Unfortunately this doc does not cover the configuration for Apache Tomcat server.

You can refer to [this block post](http://codedumpster.nithinbiliya.com/deep-linking-issue-angular-application-tomcat-server/) for configuring the fallback on Apache tomcat. This post explains setting the `PathLocationStrategy` and its server side configuration for Apache Tomcat server.